# Lost file permissions after a couple hours in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I have a user, using Windows 10, signed in on their Microsoft Account.

They have no problems when the machine has first started, but after a couple hours they get a permission error accessing .jpg's. All permissions on the file look fine, and I've tried 'unblocking' the files as well... no difference.

Do a system restart and everything goes back to normal, then a few hours later permission problem kicks in and they have to restart... and so on...

"*Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropiate permissions to access the item.*"

The permissions error popup:

[image: Permission error popup]

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the hard drive as well, if the software fixes suggested below don't work. I would wonder if the drive is faulty or failing.

Comment: Does this computer have third-party antivirus or any uncommon "management" software? Is this P drive a normal local disk, network share, or some kind of mounted cloud space? There could be a problem with the server or mount provider in the latter cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a user, using Windows 10, signed in on their Microsoft Account.

One user (only) with this problem.

Try the following:

**(1) DISM / SFC:**

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

DISM / SFC is an initial repair. It works sometimes, not all the time.

**(2) Windows 10 Repair Install:**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(3) DISM / Repair Fail:**

If the repairs above fail, either there is User Profile damage or more serious Operating System damage.

In either event, the most practical repair is to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will give it a go